# Como logro que cuando se haga click en un check me exija agregar un archivo en javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input-file

Tengo una vista de un sistema de reasignacion de prestamos, en donde se visualizan los articulos entregados de dos clientes, y quiero que al darle click a un articulo en el check no me deje hacer la reasignacion sin antes adjuntarle como minimo una foto, pues admite varios archivos, tengo un codigo pero no me funciona,  y tambien es necesario que cuando le adjunte un archivo a un articulo me exija tambien marcar el check, asi como esta el codigo me sale la alerta de de que debo adjuntar el archivo aunque este adjunto el archivo

```
                                <?php if ($prestamo["id_cliente"] == $id_cliente2) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id_producto" value="<?= $prestamo["id_producto"] ?>" id="id_producto" class="id_producto">
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="cbox" value="<?= $prestamo["id_detalle"] ?>" type="checkbox" name="cbox" id="idcliente2">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><?= $prestamo["nombre"] ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $prestamo["serial"] ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $prestamo["codigo"] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php if ($prestamo["condicion"] == 1) {
                                                echo "Nuevo";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "Usado";
                                            } ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $prestamo["comentarios"] ?></td>
                                        <td><?= "Entregado" ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $prestamo["verificar_fecha"] ?></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input type="file" name="<?= $prestamo["id_detalle"] ?>[fotos][]" id="files" name="files" onchange="vista_img(event, '<?= $prestamo['id_detalle'] ?>')" multiple>
                                            <div id="foto<?= $prestamo["id_detalle"] ?>"></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><i foto="<?= $prestamo["url_imagen"] ?>" id="fotos" type="button" class="fa fa-picture-o" style="border:none"></i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
```

este es parte del script

var Detalles = [];

```
checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.cbox');
for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            Detalles.push(this.value)
        } else {
            Detalles = Detalles.filter(e => e !== this.value)
        }

    })
}



// boton para enviar la reasignacion de los productos
jQuery('#reasignar').on('click', function() {
    let idclientes = [];
    let idDetalles = [];
    let idproducto = jQuery(".id_producto").val();
    let id_cliente1 = jQuery("#id_cliente1").val();
    let id_cliente2 = jQuery("#id_cliente2").val();
    idclientes.push(id_cliente1, id_cliente2);

    let cantidad_check1 = 0;
    let cantidad_check2 = 0;
    let cantidad = 0;


    let idform = document.getElementById("formulario");
    const formulario = new FormData(idform);

    const inputsFotos = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');
    let totalInputsConArchivos = 0;


    jQuery("input[type='file']").each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val())) {
            totalInputsConArchivos++;
        }
    });


    checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.cbox');
    for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
        if (checkbox.checked === true) {
            if (checkbox.id === "idcliente1") {
                cantidad_check1++;
            } else if (checkbox.id === "idcliente2") {
                cantidad_check2++;
            }
            cantidad++;
        }
    }



    console.log('checkboxes:', checkboxes);
    console.log('fotos:', inputsFotos);
    console.log('totalfotos:', totalInputsConArchivos);
    
        if (Detalles == '') {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Ningun producto marcado.',
                confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
            })
        } else if ($('.cbox').is(':checked')) {//es en esta parte del codigo que necesito ayuda
            $('#files').prop('required', true);

            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Por favor agregar fotos a todos los productos marcados y/o marca el producto.',
                confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
            });

        } else {

            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Esta seguro de reasignar los productos?',
                confirmButtonText: 'Si',
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                focusCancel: true
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed == true) {
                    // datos para la reasignacion 
                    axios.post('ajax/prestamo/reasignar?id=' + Detalles, formulario)

                        .then((resultado) => {.......
```

Comment: Supongamos que inicialmente no estaba _chequeado_, y luego lo _chequeaste_. Si lo volvés a desmarcar, ¿se elimina la propiedad `required` en el campo?

Comment: ¿Por qué tu `<input type="file">` tiene dos _name_? ¿Qué es la propiedad _foto_ en `<i foto="<?= $prestamo["url_imagen"] ?>"`?